# Google App Script to Delete Content on Time Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

Currently trying to get this script to run using time triggers in Google Sheets. The script itself will run. But when the time triggers occur it is not running as usual. I believe I am missing something obvious and would love input if anyone has a similar application running on Google Sheets. Here is currently what I have to run every morning. Assistance is greatly appreciated

```
 function DELETECONTENT() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('link');

//Getting the sheet associated to my spreadhseet
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TEST');

//clear contents in my spreadsheet
var app = SpreadsheetApp
var activesheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
activesheet.getRange("G2:G36").clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('link');
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('TEST');
  sh.getRange("G2:G36").clearContent();
}
```

On the trigger the active sheet will always be ss.getSheets()[0]